# Save the session from a working thread when closing

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a multi-thread VB.net program. and I want to loop through each thread and get the session from each one.

here's the code that creates the threads.

```
Sub Run():
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    AddHandler LoginTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf doWork
    LoginTimer.Interval = 500
    LoginTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

and here's the doWork() sub:

```
sub doWork()
    For id = 0 to val(textbox1.text) ' get how many thread should we run
                Dim th As New Thread(AddressOf Work) ' what the threads should do.
                th.IsBackground = True
                th.Start()
    Next id
```

Now every time I close the program, the threads became aborted and I lost all the stuff that those threads have been working on. So, I want to save the sessions. and the Next time when I run I'd just 'resume' it by loading back the sessions. Something like:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim sessions As New List(Of String)
    For Each thread In xxxx ' here where should I do a loop through the running threads
       sessions.Add(thread.session) ' get the session from the thread
    Next thread 
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I've managed to fix my problem by creating a "Public Shared ShoulIupadteNow as Boolean", since the threads i have are running in continuous loop they all the time check if the Boolean set to true. and when it is ( i usually click on a button that set it to true on my form ) it starts updating by having a public shared lstsessions as new hashset(of string) this way I won't have duplicate sessions and once all threads finished updating I loop through all the content in the hashset and then store it in txt files.

Comment: When you close the app, it's done.  If you need it to resume an operation on the next launch, you'll need to persist your 'session' to a more permanent store - like a SQL database, or XML file for example.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. but how can I get those sessions to a SQL database or XML. I need to get them from the running threads then save them.

Comment: Sorry - what you've mocked up is a little vague, so my answer is also a little generic... A starting point would be to write whatever object you're threading to a table at the beginning of your `Work` method, and delete it at the end of `Work`.  When you close your form while these threads are running, the undeleted ones will be your to-be-processed queue. The Form_Load (or wherever else appropriate) could then load those remaining/abandoned records from the previous close and process them, deleting each when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is saving stuff from each thread you may save the data you want in public variables inside a top class that calls each thread. For instance, i have a class called controlador inside a class GUI. This class handle other threads. When there is information of other threads i want to pass to class GUI i save the info inside controlador attributes and then call the attributes through class GUI. I do not know if i made my self clear. The only problem is if you want to update a control inside class GUI from one of the other threads. If this is your case you should have methods like this in GUI class:

```
Delegate Sub SetDebugLabel_Delegate(ByVal lbl As Label, ByVal text As String)

Public Sub SetDebugLabel_ThreadSafe(ByVal lbl As Label, ByVal text As String)
    If lbl.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim MyDelegate As New SetDebugLabel_Delegate(AddressOf SetDebugLabel_ThreadSafe)
            Me.Invoke(MyDelegate, New Object() {lbl, text})
    Else
        lbl.Text = text
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you should use inside the do work sub something like this:

```
 SetDebugLabel_ThreadSafe(Me.lblDataServer, ctrl.dTempo)
```

Where ctrl is the controlador class instantiated.

If you like the XML approach you could save the data you want into a datatable and then export to XML.

One way can be seen in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx or you can do it like this:

```
    Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True


Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(caminho & "alarmes.xml", settings)

   ' Begin writing.
     writer.WriteStartDocument()
     writer.WriteStartElement("CNCO") ' Root.

     With Login.user.DB1.dsDados.Tables("Lista")
         For i As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1
              writer.WriteStartElement("Duto")
              writer.WriteElementString("Nome", "Alarmes")
              writer.WriteElementString("TAG", .Rows(i)("TAG"))
              writer.WriteEndElement()
         Next

         ' End document.
         writer.WriteEndElement()
         writer.WriteEndDocument()

    End With
 End Using
```

To read the XML, simply read the path (arquivo is the path string) and restore the data into a datatable. One way could be done like this:

```
 With Login.user.DB1.dsDados
          .Tables("Lista").Clear()
          .ReadXml(arquivo)
          .Tables(0).DefaultView.Sort = "TAG DESC"
 End With
```

Comment: I was thinking of creating a public shared List in the form1 and then keep updating it. But It'd more CPU consuming which is exactly what I've been working on which is to make the program more lightweight. so It's my plan B in case no body know how to do this :)

Comment: Since nobody replied and I've managed to fix my problem I'll mark your answer as right . and I'll edit my post to mention how I fix it :)